# python set returned value from another function as a variable to use in header

Tags: python, class, authentication, header, access-token

Trying to get token as a variable in auth header in request in submit_documents() function it works fine if it was hard coded ; however I need to get from the return from log_in_as_taxpayer() function :

```
import json

class ETax_Integration(object):
    """docstring for ETax_Integration"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(ETax_Integration, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
        

    def log_in_as_taxpayer(self):
        
        client_id='###'
        # print(client_id)
        url = "https://url/connect/token"
        client_secret='###'
        # print(client_secret)
        payload={'grant_type':'client_credentials','client_id':{client_id},'client_secret':{client_secret},'scope':'InvoicingAPI'}
        headers = {
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }

        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
        values=json.loads(response.text)
        # print(values['access_token'])
        # print( response.raise_for_status())
        return (values['access_token'])

    def submit_document(self):
        token=self.log_in_as_taxpayer()
        print(token)
        submit_payload = json.dumps({
          "documents": []
        headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'
        }
        submit_url = "https://api/link"
        response = requests.request("POST", submit_url, headers=headers, data=submit_payload,verify=False)

        print(response.text)
        print( response.raise_for_status())


test=ETax_Integration(object)
# test.log_in_as_taxpayer()
test.submit_document()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f'Bearer {token}'`, notice the leading `f`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) and [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for more info or search `python f-string` with your favorite search engine ;)